# Add extra condition that excludes opposite amounts

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, summary

I have the following SQL-Query:

```
SELECT
  FGLEDG.EGCONO,
  FGLEDG.EGDIVI,
  FGLEDG.EGVONO,
  SUM(FGLEDG.EGACAM) AS BOKFBEL,
  MAX(FGLEDG.EGAIT1) AS KNT,
  MAX (FGLEDG.EGVDSC) AS VERTYP

 FROM SEUHATG2.M3PRD.FGLEDG FGLEDG

 WHERE (FGLEDG.EGCONO = 001)
 AND (FGLEDG.EGDIVI = '012')
 AND (FGLEDG.EGAIT1 IN ('2448','6995','2480'))

 GROUP BY  FGLEDG.EGCONO, FGLEDG.EGDIVI, FGLEDG.EGVONO

 HAVING SUM(FGLEDG.EGACAM) <> 0
```

And it gives me the following table in result:

```
EGCONO | EGDIVI |  EGVONO  |    BOKFBEL  | KNT  | VERTYP
-----------------------------------------------------------
    1  |   012  | 20100574 |    -4120    | 2448 | MANFAK
    1  |   012  | 20200488 |     2924,8  | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20200701 |   -10252    | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20200758 |     1674,4  | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20200792 |     -899,2  | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20200808 |    -1694,4  | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20200832 |   -15724,8  | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20200986 |    -2798,4  | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20201007 |   -54180    | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20201009 |    -7154    | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20201106 |   -36928,8  | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20202274 |    -2639,36 | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20202613 |    -5359,26 | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 20203715 |    15816,22 | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 30205552 |    -1095,5  | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 30206333 |      -51,63 | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 30206334 |       60,73 | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 30206335 |     -162,36 | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 30206473 |   121314,8  | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40200314 |   -48830    | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40200915 |    48830    | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40200925 |  -400000    | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40200926 |   400000    | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40200947 |     4616,98 | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40200948 |    -4616,98 | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40201257 | -2637868,75 | 6995 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40201315 |   551000    | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40201316 |  -551000    | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40201324 |    24393    | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40201325 |   -24393    | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40201342 |  2817000    | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40201343 | -2817000    | 2448 | BOKFORD
    1  |   012  | 40201409 |  2637868,75 | 6995 | BOKFORD
```

I would like my Query to also exclude rows with sum of amount equals zero even if EGVONO is doesn't have the same value. (For example, EGVONO 40200314 and 40200915 equals zero if one ads their amounts.)

How can I do that? And is it possible for the Query to first get the result above and then take an extra loop and make the exclusion?

Comment: No "loops" available in SQL...

Comment: Is there a way I can do this using some kind of subquery then?

Comment: But what if *one* record has an amount of 1000 and *two* other records have an amount of -1000 each? Which to remove from the results.

Comment: What DBMS are you using (MySQL or SQL Server or PostgreSQL or ...)?

Comment: And I just notice, you say "exclude rows with sum of amount equals zero". Would that also mean to remove +100 + 400 -200 -300, because these four records add up to zero?

Comment: Hmmm... Thorsten, all very good questions.

In this case my amounts are never as precise as 1000 and -1000. But good point, I had not thought of that.

I actually run my Querys in Excel 2013, I believe the DBMS is Access?

No, a +100 +400 -200 -300 should never match up to zero. Only exakt amounts, like 24393 -24393.

Comment: Okay. I don't know MS Access well (and what I have seen so far doesn't invite me to get it know better ;-) Maybe your best bet is to use a programming language, probably VBA in your case. But anyway: when you have two records with +24393 and three with -24393, which do you want removed? Without a rule it doesn't make much sense to think of a solution.

Comment: Yes, I know, running querys in Excel is not good for more advanced querys.

I'm satisfied with your answers and will try some other apporach, for example using Excel functions and filters instead.

Thank you!